# How to fix split open roof

Tags: roof, outdoor, shed

Recent winds in the UK had blown the roof off my shed. It look like it has opened from the beam. I have claim insurance on it but for the time being I had put carpet on the roof but it keeps blowing off because of the wind.

What can I do as a temporary fix so my things don't wet?

[image: open shed]

Comment: You have to fix / weight the temporary cover down. If you have ever been to a market, they can be seen using old 10lb weights to stop their tents from disappearing... :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use carpet. Water will go right through that. Buy a tarp with metal rings, and use rachet straps or ropes to fasten that to the base of the shed. Example: https://youtu.be/2X6qlhyKSjM

Hardware stores and home improvement stores sell tarps. Walmart even sells them.

Comment: Even gallon jugs of water in the rings or grommets possibly a board or 2 to keep water from sagging in the middle.